# How to view the path of DLLs hosted inside a svchost.exe or dllhost.exe process from Python?

Tags: python, windows, service

I am trying to gather a list of services and their DLLs.

From python, I get a list of services with psutil.win_service_iter():

```
import psutil
services = psutil.win_service_iter()
print(services[0].as_dict()["binpath"])
```

However, when I iterate over a service hosted in a svchost.exe or dllhost.exe process, I only get the command line to start svchost.exe or dllhost.exe from binpath. For example:

```
C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalService -p
```

I know I can view the DLLs with Process Explorer but I am searching for a way to do this programmatically in Python.

Edit: I know how to view *all* the loaded DLLs, but I only want the main DLLs, the ones containing the ServiceMain() function. Same as Process Explorer:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTNkZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could very well do it through a Python subprocess call.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-run-external-command-and-get-output/

In the Command Prompt in Windows, you would type "tasklist /SVC | findstr LocalService".  Subsequently, you could do a Python call that looks something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["tasklist", "/SVC", "| findstr LocalService"])
```